# Is there any possibility to create DB while app installing?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to create DB and insert a row with device details during the app installation. Is there any possibility to do this?

I tried to create db by using this [article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm). But it only works when app is opened. But I need to trigger the db creation process during the installation of my app.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge no, but one way to solve this,
Create an app A, Listen for "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" and when your app B is installing create DB using app A.